# How do I get access to Enable-DistributionGroup?

Tags: powershell, office365, exchange-server

I have a universal security group that I am trying to mail-enable and the PowerShell cmdlet that I need to use, `Enable-DistributionGroup` is not available for my PS session.  We are using Office365 and I am using a session with Microsoft Exchange.  I know that depending on what roles you are granted you will not have access to certain cmdlets.  But, I am a member of each role, so I would think that I have access to ALL cmdlets.  Does anyone know if there is something I am missing here?

Comment: Do you have an on-prem Exchange server? As far as I know you need to have a hybrid exchange setup (with an on prem Exchange server), this is assuming you use dirsync.

Comment: @bluuf We do not have anything on prem.  We are completely cloud based.  An Exchange engineer friend of mine suggested that I verify that I do not have any other URIs for our tenant.  That, or maybe one of the roles is conflicting with the role that should grant me the permissions I need to access that cmdlet.

Comment: according to technet (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn641234(v=exchg.160).aspx) there is no Enable-Distributiongroup in Exchange Online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written [here](http://This%20cmdlet%20is%20available%20only%20in%20on-premises%20Exchange%20Server%202016.), this cmdlet (Enable-DistributionGroup) is available only in on-premises Exchange Server and therefore not in Exchange Online (part from Office 365).

As you are searching for Exchange Online check the following howto "[Create and manage distribution groups](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124513(v=exchg.150).aspx)" which Applies to: Exchange Online, Exchange Server 2016, Office 365.